# How to find the marshallian demand of utility function $n$ goods (logit) beforehand?

Tags: utility

I have a utility function (logit) that is kinda weird and hard to work with given the constraints mentioned in the problem.

I’m trying to derive the marshallian demand for $x_0$, but I'm not sure how to. Thought of doing a transformation such that it looks like a Cobb-Douglas (however w. a e{$x_0$} in the beginning of the expression). Can’t get further than that.

I have posted the problem and my take on the problem, but I don't think my solution is correct as I don't see how this helps me realize that I can find the demand beforehand. The question is framed such that it should be obvious and trivial to find the demand. Can someone maybe help me with a hint or a solution? Thanks in advance!

The problem

[image: pic1]

My take on the problem

[image: pic2]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have now tried to clarify the problem and my take on it.